# How to make an element (<a>) stretch to the full width of its parent element (container)?

Tags: html, css

I made a responsive menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/7vmCZ/2/

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Menu 1
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Menu 111</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Menu 22</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Menu 3333</a></li>
            <li>Menu 44
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Menu 111111</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Menu 22</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Menu 3333</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Menu 44</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/">Menu 2222</a></li>
    <li>Menu 33<ul><li>This submenu should be under Menu33</li></ul></li>
        <li><a href="/">Menu 4444444</a></li>
</ul>

a
{
    background-color: red;
}

#nav {
    display:table;
}
#nav > li {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    width:1%;
}
#nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    text-indent:10px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border-top:1px #000 solid;
    border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
ul {
    display:none;
}
li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
ul#nav > li:hover > ul {
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#nav > li ul li ul {
    left:100%;
    top:-2px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
}
li, li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
* {box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
```

the problem is, the menus are clickable, and the  tag wont fit all its container (thats why I highlighted with red color). How to dodge it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
a {
  display: block;
}
```

Possibly add `width: 100%;` also,

`<a>` elements are `display: inline` by default, so the width will only be as wide as the text and any padding added to the element. `display: block` will make it take up the available width.

In case you still have problems, don't forget about the parent element's padding. The child can only take up as much space as is available to it. The parent padding may prevent it from stretching all the way to the edge of the parent. This will also be the case with the element's margin. If the `a` tag here has a margin, this will put space around it.

Comment: yea, thats ok. Its not in my example, but then how to align the text to middle? In other words, it nullifies the previous "text-align: center;" setting

Comment: @JohnSmith add `text-align: center;` to the `a` tag.

Comment: this is what in the DIV instead of plain text:

<div class="menuIcons"><div class="menuWrapper"><img alt="home icon" src="/design/_menu/home.gif" /><div class="menuText">Home</div></div></div>

and it wont go center easily :S

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm not sure what you mean. Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/pQVV6/

Comment: Id rather close this and open a new

Comment: @JohnSmith you asked for it to cover the whole `li`. If you don't want it to cover the whole thing, remove `display: block`...but then, what's your question?

Comment: yes, it was the question originally, but I have nested div-s in the LI now, than simple text

Comment: @JohnSmith A new post detailing whatever issue you're having would be helpful. You would need to include the relevant html, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Here you go

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/7vmCZ/3/

```
li {
    text-align:center;
}
a
{
    background-color: red;
    display:block;
}
```

For the filled BG, use `display:block;`

For the alignment, target your `li` items.

**If you just want your top level list items centered, use a basic `text-align` on all `li` items, then a `psuedo class` to direct descendants of your `ul#nav`.**

```
ul#nav li {
    text-align:left;
}
ul#nav > li {
    text-align:center;
}
```